# PHP search with PDO

Tags: php, search, pdo

I am trying to convert search function from one tutorial from mysql into PDO. I need to search inside of my table. With my limited knowledge I was able to do this. However, there are still some things I cannot resolve. What I am missing?
When searching no matter what I search I still get no result.

**ORIGINAL**

```
if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){

  $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);

  $query = $db->query(
  "SELECT name, description
   FROM cars 
   WHERE name LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR description LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
  ");
  ?>

  <div class="result-count">
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results.
  </div>

  <?php
  if($query->num_rows){
    while ($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
      ?>
      <div class="result">
        <a href="#"><?php echo $r->name; ?></a>
      </div>
  <?php
    }
  }
}
?>
```

**PDO version/my version**

```
  <?php
  include 'inc/header.php';

if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){
  $keywords = $_GET['keywords'];

  $cars = $db->prepare("SELECT name, description FROM cars WHERE name LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR description LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
  ");
  $cars->execute();

 ?>
<div class="result-count">
  Found <?php echo $cars->rowCount(); ?> results.
</div>

<?php
  if($cars->rowCount()){
    while($r = $cars->fetchObject()){
      ?>
      <div class="result">
        <a href="#"><?php echo $r->name; ?></a>
      </div>
  <?php
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

Html

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="keywords" value="SEARCH" autocomplete="off">
  </label>
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: What happens with this code? You are misusing prepared statements. `$cars = $db->prepare("SELECT name, description FROM cars WHERE name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?
  ");` then bind, `$cars->execute(array('%' . $keywords . '%', '%' . $keywords . '%'));` In both queries `keywords` is a string, not a variable so I don't know how it ever worked.

Comment: You're *almost* there, but you're *still* open to mysql injection. Look into prepared statements, totally. Especially the parts where you bind values.

Comment: Currently : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on array. Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Comment: You re-assigned the variable from a PDO object. `$cars = $cars->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. The `while($r = $cars->fetchObject()){` also is not needed/going to work. You already fetched with the `fetchall`.

Comment: @chris85 By removing $cars = $cars->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); I dont get any error but I still get no result from search

Comment: Did you update the query? I was more proposing you change the variable name there but you could do the latter approach too.

Comment: $chris85 you was right. I missed $ sign in keywords. It was there in original version I just missed it to copy it. And of course I missed it to write in my PDO version. After adding $ into keywords I managed to get it working. Thank you!

Comment: My code wasn't missing the `$`. Did you use that query or your original?

Comment: Both my example and my version were missing $. I just added them where needed and it worked. I did not use your query